# Getting 'Invalid value' error when setting timestamp value in Firestore using Arduino and ESP32

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I'm working on a project that involves using an Arduino board and an ESP32 microcontroller to interact with Google Firestore. I'm trying to set a timestamp value in Firestore using the Arduino code, but I keep encountering an 'Invalid value' error.
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
struct tm timeinfo;
if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
}
char timestamp[20]; //YYYY-MM-DD_HR:MN:SC\0
strftime(timestamp, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
content.set("fields/timestamp", timestamp);
```

`Invalid value at 'document.fields[6].value' (type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Value), '2023-05-13'`

My other ones work like:

```
content.set("fields/dateTime/stringValue", dateTimeString);
content.set("fields/temperature/doubleValue", temp_f);
```

I tried a bunch of things and nothing worked. How can I solve this?